# UIScrollView Frame Always CGRectZero

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I have a nib that has the standard `UIView` and I've also included a `UIScrollView` as an `IBOutlet` (yes, it is hooked up), not as a subview of the main `UIView`, but just out on its own. **Autolayout is turned off**. The scroll view has several subviews and is larger than the main view. In `viewWillAppear:`, I set the content size of the `UIScrollView` to its current frame size, and then set its frame to the size of the main view, and add it as a subview of the main view.

Unfortunately, nothing is showing up. When I `NSLog` the frame of my `UIScrollView`, it is coming back as `{0, 0, 0, 0}` (`CGRectZero`). I thought this was odd, so I went back and tried logging the frame before I do any changes to it. Still zeroes. Logged it out in `viewDidLoad` before anything is done to any of my view elements. Still zeroes. (FWIW in my nib, the frame is `{0, 0, 320, 896}`)

I've had this issue with several of my controllers, but it seems to be hit or miss. Sometimes it works, other times I get the empty frame. Typically, recreating everything from scratch seems to fix the issue, but I don't know why, as I'm setting everything up the same both times.

Running Xcode version 6.1 (6A1052d), iOS SDK 8.1 with a deployment target of 7.0

Let me know if there is any other relevant information I can give that might help.

---

EDIT 1: To address the questions about my `UIScrollView` being a "subview", here is what my view heirarchy looks like in the document outline:
[image: Document Outline]
As you can see, the `UIScrollView` is a "subview" of the view controller, but is not a subview of the "main" `UIView` which has the controller's `view` outlet.

---

EDIT 2: More images and some code. Here is a better look at how my nib is set up:
[image: Nib Screenshot]

I add my `scrollView` to the main `UIView` as follows:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    scrollView.contentSize = scrollView.frame.size;
    scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 100); // I slightly modified this because there are other variables that determine its Y position and height
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView]
}
```

**But I still don't think any of that code matters**- for whatever reason, my `UIScrollView` is coming back `nil`. If I have the view created in my nib, the outlet is connected properly, how would the view still be nil? I'm creating my controller via `initWithNibName` I've tried cleaning the project, and removing the app and reinstalling.

Comment: Are you sure the object is not nil in the view controller? If you are setting the frame and immediately after logging it, the only reason I can see for it returning zero is for the object to be nil, and thus ignore the call to `setFrame:`.

Comment: @pgb WTH you're right- it appears to be `nil`. That doesn't make any sense either though. I even just removed and re-hooked the `IBOutlet` connection and it's still `nil`.

Comment: What do you mean "not as a subview of the main `UIView`, but just out on its own"? If it isn't in the subview hierarchy of your view controller's view, it won't appear on screen...

Comment: Is the IBOutlet a `strong` reference?

Comment: @pgb it is not. It is declared as `IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;` in the implementation file in brackets after the @implementation.

Comment: @IanMacDonald I mean that it is not placed as a subview of the `UIView` that has the view controller's `view` outlet. There is a `UIView` and a `UIScrollView` that are both "subviews" of the view controller, but they are separate in the nib.

Comment: What do you mean when you say the scrollview in your interface is not a subview? How's that possible?

Comment: Wow, turns out @ianmacdonald and I posted the same exact thing haha... Sorry, my internet's slow.

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: @Stonz2 I'm not sure I'm following you. A view controller can't have a subview; only its view can.

Comment: @pgb the OP's using nibs. And OP, can you post (1) a screencap of your interface builder and (2) your viewWillAppear code?

Comment: @Stonz2 to make it clear to you and others... Views are not "subviews" of view controllers. In your case, they are both root objects on the nib file. As it gets deserialised, both objects (View and Scroll View) will be created.

Comment: @pgb I am not. I use individual nib files due to my somewhat complicated navigation structure. Ian, check the edit for more info. I tried moving the declaration of the scroll view to the header just for poops and laughs but it didn't change anything. I can post relevant code, but as I said in the question, the scroll's frame is coming back as 0s in `viewDidLoad` which shouldn't happen either AFAIK.

Comment: @pgb Yes. And I'm about to post more images and some code.

Comment: @Stonz2 Just added a best guess answer. I'm pretty sure you are losing you are losing the reference as it's being deallocated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best guess on an answer, and some comments:

- Nibs are simply serialised object trees. You can have as many view as you want as root. The problem (big one!) is that if they are not "connected" to outlets that `retain` them, at some point you will loose those references.

Since your `UIScrollView` is not a subview of the main view controller view on the Nib, it's not retained by it (views retain their subviews). So, it's up to you to retain it on your view controller.

My guess is that at the point you are trying to set the frame in the View Controller, the scroll view is already gone. I'm not sure how sure when are you doing it, but it might be after some run loops, so the unretained scroll view is dealloced.

#### Workarounds:

1. Instead of a variable for the `IBOutlet`, use a strong property (`@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView`).
2. Add the `__strong` qualifier to the variable.
3. Add the `UIScrollView` as a subview *within* the nib, so when the object tree is deserialised it's already retained by its parent.

Given that you purposefully put the `UIScrollView` outside of the main view hierarchy, I'm assuming you don't want option 3, so I'll just go with 1.

Comment: Making my `IBOutlet` strong appears to have fixed the issue. And yeah, don't want option 3. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you might want to consider using autolayout. It makes things a *lot* easier once you make the investment to understand how it works. Check out this [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html) on using UIScrollview with autolayout.

If that's not an option, the problem is that you're setting up your scrollView at the wrong point in the cycle. The scrollView needs a chance to lay itself out. By the time you hit viewWillAppear, you've missed sub view layout.

So, you could try:

1. Configure your scrollView in willLayoutSubviews and set its setNeedsLayout property.
2. Explicitly call layoutIfNeeded on your scrollView in viewWillAppear. The idea is to force another subview layout cycle. But, I'm not 100% sure it would work -- it might be too late at that point.

Note that the size of the main view (self.view) isn't determined until viewDidAppear.  It's not always correct in viewWillAppear.  So, you have a problem in your setup: you can't really set up your scrollView until you know your view size, but you don't know that until it's too late! You might want to redesign to avoid that dependency.